# $T_n:=$ number of ways $n$ balls(which are the same) can be distributed in different boxes such that in each box there are at least 2 balls

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Find recurrent formula for $T_n$

IMPORTANT: number of boxes is not limited.

Usually in problems of this kind it is easy to understand what happens with $n$-th element when it comes into play but in this case it doesn't seem to be that easy. For example, there exist situation, where if we take $n$-th ball out of box, $T_{n-1}$ can be invalid (if we took it from box where were only two elements)

Comment: Hi, I have some questions: 1) $n$ is the number of balls? 2) the configurations with $6$ balls and $2$ boxes $4-2$ and $2-4$ are different?

Comment: @Menezio 1) yes 2) yes, since boxes are different

Comment: @ChristianBlatter sorry, n is number of balls

Comment: And when you say "box are unlimited" you mean that if you have $2k=n$ balls you have to consider all the cases with $1,2,...,k$ boxes?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter number of boxes is not limited means that there can be as many boxes as we want. For example, in case we have 4 balls , there can be such distributions: 4; 2,2 (If we would take more than 2 boxes it is not problem but there will be exactly 0 ways to distribute balls such that in each box there will be not less than 2 balls)

Comment: @Menezio yes, you are right, other cases can be considered but they will all give 0 distributions

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanations, I suggest to edit you question in order to be more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering the number of balls in the last box, we get
$$
T_n=T_{n-2}+T_{n-3}+T_{n-4}+\dots+T_2
$$
For example, if the last box contains $3$ balls, then the remaining $n-3$ balls must be put into boxes in $T_{n-3}$ ways.

You can then modify this recurrence so that it only has a bounded number of terms. If you take the above equation with $n-1$ substituted for $n$, you get
$$
T_{n-1}=T_{n-3}+T_{n-4}+\dots+T_2
$$
Now, subtracting the second from the first,
$$
T_{n}-T_{n-1}=T_{n-2}\implies T_{n}=T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}
$$
That is, $T_n$ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence! With hindsight, you can prove this recurrence directly:

- If the last box has more than $3$ balls, then removing one ball from the last box leaves a distribution of $n-1$ balls.
- If the last box has $2$ balls, then removing those $2$ balls leaves a distribution of $n-2$ balls.

Comment: Cool solution! Thank you!

Comment: You finally found out what the question was!

Answer (score 1):

I propose a direct approach without a recurrent formula.

Suppose $n=2k$, then we can have good cases only for a number of boxes equal to $1,...,k$.

Consider $i = $ number of boxes. Now we put $2$ balls in each box by default. Then it reamains only $2k-2i$ balls that we can put as we want in the $i$ boxes.

The number of ways we can do this is easy to compute (anagrams of words with $2k-2i$ letter $A$ and $i-1$ letter $B$):
$$
\binom{2k-2i+i-1}{i-1} = \binom{2k-i-1}{i-1}
$$

The sum over $i$ is the answer to your question:
$$
T_n = T_{2k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{2k-i-1}{i-1}
$$

The case $n=2k+1$ is really similar and it gives:

$$
T_n = T_{2k+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \binom{2k-i}{i-1}
$$

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to express it through some previous values of $T$?